# awk prints new column on a new line

Tags: bash, calculated-columns, data-manipulation, awk

please suggest me how to fix this annoying issue.
I use awk to make a simple calculation and then print the result on a new  tab separated column. It works, but awk prints the result on a column on a new line. Please have a look

```
     chr1   839976  840333  44  66151894
     chr1   855835  856060  23  66151894
     chr1   860112  860337  25  66151894

awk 'BEGIN { OFS = "\t" } { $6 = $3-$2 } 1 ' file1.txt > result1.txt
```

This command print something like this

```
   chr1 713869 714267 79 66151894
   398
   chr1 839976 840333 44 66151894
   357
   chr1 855835 856060 23 66151894
   225
```

Can you fix the command properly?

Comment: Did you edit this file in a DOS environment? Did you look for carriage return (`\r\n`) ? Can you post output of `hexdump -c file1.txt` ?

Comment: This is a simple Windows formatted text, saved with excel

Comment: Ah! Thats seems to be the problem. `DOS` line endings are not compatible when running  in Linux. Just do `dos2unix file1.txt` before running the `Awk` in Linux

Comment: @Inian,Apologies Inian, I just now saw you have given same suggestion to check OP about carriage characters, though I have given a different command to remove then, sorry it was not intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your command it works fine for me, as a assumption could you please check if you have carriage characters in your Input_file by doing `cat -v Input_file` then you could use following commands to remove them first.

```
tr -d '\r' < Input_file > temp_file && mv temp_file Input_file
```

Then you could give a shot to your own command.